# Error when trying to open a winform from an asp page

Tags: c#, winforms, asp-classic, infopath

I have a simple winform that just has a Microsoft.Office.Infopath.FormControl object as a child control, and basically does nothing. When I run a standalone project, the form opens fine, but when called from an asp page ( Visual studio development environment), I get the following error.

Unable to get the window handle for the 'FormControl' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported.

After a little research, I found that it might be because of MTA threads. I also set the apartment state to STA, and still am getting the same error.

This is required for a bigger project i'm working on to open infopath as a COM object.

Please advice.

P.S -- There is no need for example code because there is practically no code at all. All i'm doing in the asp page is :

Form1 myform = new Form1();

myform.Show();

//or

myform.ShowDialog();

Its really urgent!!

Comment: This is not a threading issue, it's simply not possible. Web pages don't even *have* threads.

Comment: I think rerun is right...because no mesage loop is present...it cannot open via the web page..But will it open if i used it in a web service?

Answer (score 2):

You can not open a form from a web project.  There is no message loop or even a desktop to display it on.  You can interact with programs on the server but that is general done though a windows service which also shouldn't display forms.  You need to reexamine your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...I had a doubt...will it run if i used a web service?

Comment: the goal is to launch a winform from a website...the winform has an infopath editor environment...so forms from a sharepoint can be opened..so when the website is launched and a button is clicked...the winform can be called and the form can be processed...all this is being done because forms services is not enabled...P.S..I'm not opening an exe from the web service...only a Form.Show() or Form.Showdialog()...

Comment: are you in a homogeneous environment where you can dictate machine setup

Comment: if you mean whether the browsers that will view the website all have .Net framework enabled, then yes. And i have IIS on my desktop that will deploy the website for usage within the internal network

Comment: You had it right the first time: this can't be done. You can show the form on the web server, but that won't have anything to do with the pages shown on the users' machines.

Comment: @Cody Hi, I am also working on this project.  The goal is to open the form on the web server, programatically take a screenshot of the form, and return it through the web service.  Would that theoretically be possible?

Comment: yes.  You would need to find some type of IPC to do the communication.  A better solution would be to move the code in winform to a wcf service

Comment: Hm, I believe we experimented with this before and ran into to some issues. I guess we'll have to consider revisiting it.  Thank you for your help.